# Rails - Devise, Email Case Insensitivity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using Devise with login credentials: email/password - no usernames

I just noticed that the login process is case sensitive for emails. so if you register with bob@apPle.com, and then try to log in with Bob@apple.com you get an error. Very confusing.

How can I make devise log people in with their email/password, and the email being case insensitive?

Comment: Note: The behavior described above doesn't (as of 1.2?) seem to be the default behavior anymore.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One option is to override the find method used by devise. Something like:

```
# User.rb
before_save do
  self.email.downcase! if self.email
end

def self.find_for_authentication(conditions) 
  conditions[:email].downcase! 
  super(conditions) 
end
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Is there anyway to let the user save their email anyway they want, but use the find_for_authentication to downcase what's inputted and what's in the database to avoid this issue? Thoughts?

Comment: It is possible. You will most likely have to override `find_for_authentication fully` without the parent call (and perform the lookup yourself) but I am not exactly sure what conditions are passed in.

Comment: Did anyone figure out the solution for storing it case-sensitive but making it case-insensitive during login?

Answer (score 75):

You can easily fix the issue like below.

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email, :username]
end
```

Comment: This looks like the most correct way to make login case-insensitive. (And it just worked for me -- Thanks!)

Comment: Confirmed 2/15/2012 on Devise 1.4.2.  It's not in the online wiki as far as I can tell

Comment: Make sure to run a migration to downcase any existing emails or usernames in the database as well.

Comment: Also, you may have to use the `<attribute>_will_change!` method to get ActiveRecord to change your data because with `case_insensitive_keys` set for the model AR no longer things the email or username has changed  just by downcasing it.

Comment: This is not the best option if you've got two Devise models (User/Admin) with different requirements, though.

Answer (score 5):

I added this to my User model to store it case-sensitive but make it case-insensitive during sign in:

```
def self.find_for_database_authentication(conditions = {})
  self.where("LOWER(email) = LOWER(?)", conditions[:email]).first || super
end
```

It works on Heroku.

By the way, this is just a temporary fix as the issue has been resolved and this will be the default behavior on Devise 1.2. See [this pull request](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/670) for details.

Comment: I really think this is the best answer, especially on an app where emails are visible to (some) users. People should have the option to capitalize their email as they like , PLUS this requires no updating of your current database.

Comment: Note that the fix in the pull request is *not* the same as the code that Andrés provided. The newer devises will only search for downcased emails if configured so, but will not guarantee that the email fields are downcased when saved. You will still have problems finding a downcased email addresses if it has capitalization in the db with the newer devise versions, while the code above will successfully look up differently capitalised versions.

Comment: Also note that as [the comments here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/3d9dea39b2978e3168604ccda956fb6ec17c5e27/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L237) mention, this will only make emails case insensitive for authentication and not for password resetting for example.

Comment: Correction, devise does try to downcase emails on saving, but it is not always successful if there is other code in the mix.

Answer (score 0):

I also had some solution which making work with email is case-insensitive for all Devise controllers (functionality):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
...
...
  prepend_before_filter :email_to_downcase, :only => [:create, :update]
...
...
  private
...
...
  def email_to_downcase
    if params[:user] && params[:user][:email]
      params[:user][:email] = params[:user][:email].downcase
    end
  end
...
...
end
```

I know it is not the best solution: it involves another controllers of another models and executes code which is not necessary for them. But it was just makeshift and it works (at least for me ;) ).

Kevin and Andres, thanks for your answers. It is really good solutions and useful. I wanted to vote them up, but I haven't enough reputation yet. So, I just tell 'thanks' to you. ;)

Lets wait for Devise 1.2

Answer (score 0):

Devise addresses the issue here:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address